# How to Group By Same Value In Multidimensional Array And Calculate Sum

Tags: php, foreach

I'm trying to create a simple report that will display how much money is being made per month. I'd like to group by month and calculate sum of that month.

This is what the array looks like :

```
$payouts = Array
(
    [0] => Stripe\Payout Object
        (
            [id] => po_1F8dyGDi2QUa2pDzir2SvvEJ
            [object] => payout
            [amount] => 11291
            [arrival_date] => 1566172800
            [automatic] => 1
            [balance_transaction] => txn_1F8dyGDi2QUa2pDzYSkN2Kq4
            [created] => 1566094696
            [currency] => cad
            [description] => STRIPE PAYOUT
            [destination] => ba_1EzNmkDi2QUa2pDzApl8u4hs
            [failure_balance_transaction] => 
            [failure_code] => 
            [failure_message] => 
            [livemode] => 
            [metadata] => Stripe\StripeObject Object
                (
                )

            [method] => standard
            [source_type] => card
            [statement_descriptor] => 
            [status] => paid
            [type] => bank_account
        )

    [1] => Stripe\Payout Object
        (
            [id] => po_1F8HDoDi2QUa2pDz9BSKsIv2
            [object] => payout
            [amount] => 11339
            [arrival_date] => 1566172800
            [automatic] => 1
            [balance_transaction] => txn_1F8HDoDi2QUa2pDz3s2iAaZ4
            [created] => 1566007248
            [currency] => cad
            [description] => STRIPE PAYOUT
            [destination] => ba_1EzNmkDi2QUa2pDzApl8u4hs
            [failure_balance_transaction] => 
            [failure_code] => 
            [failure_message] => 
            [livemode] => 
            [metadata] => Stripe\StripeObject Object
                (
                )

            [method] => standard
            [source_type] => card
            [statement_descriptor] => 
            [status] => paid
            [type] => bank_account
        )

    [2] => Stripe\Payout Object
        (
            [id] => po_1F26tNDi2QUa2pDzVuHCdFie
            [object] => payout
            [amount] => 52344
            [arrival_date] => 1564617600
            [automatic] => 1
            [balance_transaction] => txn_1F26tNDi2QUa2pDz4wKioVNf
            [created] => 1564537573
            [currency] => cad
            [description] => STRIPE PAYOUT
            [destination] => ba_1EzNmkDi2QUa2pDzApl8u4hs
            [failure_balance_transaction] => 
            [failure_code] => 
            [failure_message] => 
            [livemode] => 
            [metadata] => Stripe\StripeObject Object
                (
                )

            [method] => standard
            [source_type] => card
            [statement_descriptor] => 
            [status] => paid
            [type] => bank_account
        )

    [3] => Stripe\Payout Object
        (
            [id] => po_1EwJllDi2QUa2pDzKPpXfMe6
            [object] => payout
            [amount] => 22366
            [arrival_date] => 1563235200
            [automatic] => 1
            [balance_transaction] => txn_1EwJllDi2QUa2pDzXM0S3sBv
            [created] => 1563157105
            [currency] => cad
            [description] => STRIPE PAYOUT
            [destination] => ba_1EvDDqDi2QUa2pDzpdVr5PLg
            [failure_balance_transaction] => 
            [failure_code] => 
            [failure_message] => 
            [livemode] => 
            [metadata] => Stripe\StripeObject Object
                (
                )

            [method] => standard
            [source_type] => card
            [statement_descriptor] => 
            [status] => paid
            [type] => bank_account
        )

)
```

This is the code I have that will display the months and amounts in a readable way for humans.

```
   <table>
            <thead> 
                                 <tr>
                                    <th>Date Created</th>
                                     <th>Arrival Date</th>
                                      <th>Month</th>
                                       <th>Year</th>
                                  <th>Amount</th>

                                 </tr>
                                 </thead>
                                 <tbody>

                                 <?php 
                                 $totalRevenueBE = 0;
                                 $convertedRBE = 0;
                                 foreach ($payouts->data as $payout) {

                                     $amount_gross = $payout->amount;
                                     $stripe_fee = $payout->fee;
                                     $amount_net = $amount_gross -$stripe_fee;

                                      //convert amount_net to dollars : $1 = 100cents
                                    $convertedAmount = $amount_net / 100;

                                     //calculate total revenue BE
                                    $total = $amount_net;
                                    $totalRevenueBE += $total;  

                                      //convert revenueBE_total to dollars : $1 = 100cents
                                    $convertedRBE = $totalRevenueBE / 100;

                                    //convert unix timestamp to date
                                    $date_created=$payout->created;
                                    $date_available=$payout->arrival_date;
                                    $d_created = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date_created);
                                    $d_available = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date_available);

                                     ?>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><?=$d_created?></td>
                                             <td><?=$d_available?></td>
                                                 <td><?=date('F',strtotime($d_created))?></td>
                                                  <td><?=date('Y',strtotime($d_created))?></td>
                                         <td><?=$convertedAmount?></td>

                                     </tr>
                                    <?php }?>
                                 </tbody>


        </table>
```

This is what the above codes display:

```
Date Created        | Arrival Date        | Month | Year | Amount
2019-08-18 04:18:16 |2019-08-19 02:00:00  | August| 2019 | 112.91
2019-08-17 04:00:48 |2019-08-19 02:00:00  | August| 2019 | 113.39
2019-07-31 03:46:13 |2019-08-01 02:00:00  | July  | 2019 | 523.44
2019-07-15 04:18:25 |2019-07-16 02:00:00  | July  | 2019 | 223.66
```

But this is the desired results I would want. I would like to group by month and calculate sum.

```
 Month | Year | Amount
 August| 2019 | 226.3
 July  | 2019 | 747.1
```

Comment: Hi @Random, you can get desire result by using Mqsql query only

Comment: _“But this is the desired results I would want.”_ - and where is your attempt to get it? What where the specific problems with it? Please note that this is not a code-writing service, you are supposed to show a reasonable effort first of all. [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
move desire data to another array  and use that for display 
 <?php
$data_array=[];  
$month= date('F',strtotime($d_created));
$year=date('Y',strtotime($d_created));

$sum=isset($data_array[$year][$month]['amount'])?$data_array[$year][$month]['amount']:0;
$data_array[$year][$month]['month']=$month;
$data_array[$year][$month]['year']=$year;
$data_array[$year][$month]['amount']=$sum+$convertedAmount;

 echo "<pre>";print_r($data_array); ?

> Blockquote
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the answer. I was wondering, is there a more dynamic way to access the values in the array? Right now I do  `foreach ($data_array as $n_transaction) {echo $n_transaction['August']['amount'];}` But If I have 12 months, that would mean I would need to check if each month exists within the array to access it? I dont want to access each month manually.

Comment: Hi Random use  another foreach <table>
<thead> 
<tr>
<th>Month</th>
<th>Year</th>
<th>Amount</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($data_array as $key => $data_value) { 
foreach ($data_value as $key => $value) {
?>
<tr>
<td><?=$value['month']?></td>
<td><?=$value['year']?></td>
<td><?=$value['amount']?></td>
</tr>
<?php } }?>
</tbody></table>